# Switching circuit and reducing noise

Tags: stm32, opto-isolator, switching

Need your opinion in a design I'm working on. Please see circuit below. 
So I need to control the mcu GPIO based on the incoming 24V signal. The signal is attached below. My issue is this 2 times out of 10 times, the mcu will not detect this signal. I tried adding 100n cap between 24V and GND, also tried increased 51k to 1M. But didn't make much difference.
Opto's minimum required current is 10mA.
Also, my second question, there is another channel in the 24V signal source, and when that switches sometimes my mcu detects that. Guessing thats due to noise. If you guys can suggest any improvements and get rid of incoming noise, it would be greatly appreciated. 
Last two images are the noise.

[image: switching circuit]

[image: incoming 24v signal]

[image: noise from another channel of the signal source]

[image: noise 2 from another channel of the signal source]

Comment: Show how you connected the scope probe. That looks like artifacts from too high inductance.

Comment: I connected between 24v and GND.

Comment: Also another observation- I tried measuring voltage between base and emitter of Q3 using the oscilloscope and whenever I connected the circuit worked perfectly fine - as in picking up all incoming  signals.

Comment: No, show your probe setup.

Comment: Which optocoupler?

Comment: Opto - https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/9055277907998/ZD1928-dataSheetMain.pdf

Comment: You need to show us your power setup. you have two 5Vs two grounds and 24V from somewhere....  Also zoom in, what  do the 24V edges really look like...

Comment: Define 24V input threshold desired and duration for Vout= "0" and "1". Keep 10:1 probe ground very short. Use twisted pair for any wires.